# Shopify (RTL) photo slider Premium theme

Tags: javascript, css, shopify, themes, right-to-left

I've managed to edit all the other elements to match RTL conversion,

But I didn't solve the photo slider (when I swipe left the image will switch to the right position,
it should do the opposite.
**
PROBLEM WITH MOBILE ONLY**

I need to reverse the photo carousel,

Here is the link for my website:
https://nerostudio.co.il/products/demo-x-2?variant=45467990131006

I think that they are using **Flickity slider library** and I found the RightToLeft: true command, but I don't know where to put it.

I appreciate your help!
Thank you!

I've tried to invert the touch-action or change the carousel order.